# Compatibility Mode vs IE Version Emulation

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

Is there a difference between the two? I have a web page which IE has a had time processing the Javascript. When I enable Compat mode manually within the toolbar everything works fine.

I did some research on how to force compat mode within the code. What I found was to include a meta tag which tells IE to emulate a specified browser version, like such:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` or `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >`

I've tried both, inserting them immediately after the opening head tag, but no success. IE still chokes on the javascript.

Much thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you stick them inside the `<head>` tag, or immediately after your opening `<html>`?

Comment: (.. perhaps the IE ECMAScript engine just isn't fast enough? :D Although, if chokes means "doesn't work at all", then perhaps the relevant JavaScript/error should be included ..)

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
[Here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm) there are more options. 
[Here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/internetexplorer/qt/force-compatibility-view-in-ie.htm) it explain that another way to force compatibility mode is to leave out the DOCTYPE declaration!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies. I included the meta tags inside the head tag. IE does choke up on the JS but it eventually renders everything as needed. All other browsers render the JS quickly. It's definitely an IE problem. Leaving the Doctype declaration out may be a hard sell for the other programmers on the project. Though I may try the article's suggestion of input an xml declaration above the doctype.